# How to include different Javascript files depending on build configuration?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Is there a way to include a different Javascript file in an ASP.NET page depending whether it's a debug or release build?

For release builds, I want to include the minified (using yuicompressor) Javascript, but I would like to use the more readable file for debug and development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one of two things ... either rename the appropriate file to the filename referenced in the html in a postbuild step, or dynamically include the html based on the preprocessor symbol.

Comment: I think I'll go with the renaming in a postbuild step. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

For development, if you're using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 you can also take advantage of the improved support for JavaScript IntelliSense. Scott Gu has a blog post here:

> [jQuery Intellisense in VS2008](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx)

The basic set up is:

1. Install Hotfix [KB958502](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1736)
2. Reference release versions of your .js files as you would normally
3. Ensure that you have the "development" version of the .js file sitting next to it, called *-vs-doc.js or *.debug.js

This will get you all the intellisense for the files.